# Changing y-axis tick labels from standard form to the full number

Tags: r

I made a scatterplot and the y-axis range runs from 0 to 800,000. How can I make the y-axis ticks show the numbers ("0", "200,000", "400,000", "600,000", "800,000") instead of their standard forms ("0e+00", "2e+05", "4e+05", "6e+05", "8e+05")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the **scipen** option in `?options`. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(100, min = 0, max = 1000000),
                  y = runif(100, min = 0, max = 1000000))

layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))
plot(y ~ x, data = dat)
opt <- options(scipen = 10)
plot(y ~ x, data = dat)
options(opt)
layout(1)
```

Which produces:

[image: scipen_plot]

Other options include suppressing the axes with `axes = FALSE` in the `plot()` call and then use `axis()` to add your own axes with custom supplied labels using `format()`; see `?format` for details. This is the way to go if you really want the "," in the numbers separating the thousands.

Comment: +1 -- Unless you (the OP) need the commas in your tick labels, this is the way to go. If you *do* need them, I believe you'll have to use `format()` or suchlike, as in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if the `,` were intended or not.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks for explaining both methods, I found it very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example to get you started:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- runif(10) * 1e6

yrange <- c(0, 1e6)
ticks <- pretty(yrange)
labels <- format(ticks, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)

plot(y~x, yaxt="n", ylim = yrange)
axis(2, at = ticks, labels = labels, las = 1, cex.axis=0.7)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use format and scientific=FALSE:

```
a<-c(100000, 200000)
format(a, scientific=FALSE)
```

Comment: I presume you mean to add something along the lines of plotting your own axis with your own labels? Otherwise this makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to create your own axis labels as Josh posted above. It comes in handy for currencies as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dplyr` function:

`scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)`